# Forms in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I saw different types of declaration of forms in laravel.
So when to use regular(html) type :

```
<form></form>
```

When to use laravel type:

```
{{ Form::open()}}
```

and when this:

```
{!! Form::open()!!}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Laravel's  blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade):

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks while `{!! !!}`
>   displays Unescaped characters.

Keep in mind, the `Form` syntax has been [removed in Laravel 5](https://laravel-news.com/new-community-project-laravel-collective), so to use it you will need to install a [separated package by Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html).

As per laravel's collective documentation, the correct syntax would be using the unscaped characters:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}
    //
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 you should use:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
```

Instead of:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
```

Laravel Collective Form will generate plain HTML form for you. It's just easier to build maintainable forms with Laravel Collective but if you don't want to use it for some reason, you can always build a form manually by using:

```
<form></form>
```